# "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0" on device using jumphost

Tags: ssh, connection, channel, allocation

I have an issue while trying to connect to my SSH host using a Jumphost
My authentication on host is accepte, but I got rejected with an error "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0"

I have no clue what's going on on my machine, could you please assist ?

Here is my .ssh/config content:

```
Host jumphost
    Port 2352
    Hostname <jumphost_IPADDRESS>
    User myUsername

Host myHost
    User myUsername
    Hostname <IPADDRESS>
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost
```

Here is the full log of the session i'm attempting:

```
❯ ssh -v myHost
OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 3.0.6 11 Oct 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myUsername/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/config line 37: Applying options for myHost
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myUsername/.fig/ssh
debug1: Executing command: 'command -v fig && fig _ generate-ssh myUsername'
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myUsername/.fig/ssh_inner
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W <IPADDRESS>:22 jumphost
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.1
myUsername@jumphost's password:
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSH
debug1: compat_banner: no match: SSH
debug1: Authenticating to <IPADDRESS>:22 as 'myUsername'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:pmnt0weWX0MB2jaD6F+YfUo3kGcwGM2sRJV2TypHTW0
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '<IPADDRESS>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:9M18alruYmtIxO1EHnQihCPW9G+oBFcOBlRyfJhE4uc
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
***********************       WARNING      **************************
You must have prior authorization to access this system. All
connections are logged and monitored.By connecting to this system you
fully consent to all monitoring. Unauthorized access or use will be
prosecuted to the  full extent of the law. You have been warned.

*************************************************************************
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myUsername@<IPADDRESS>'s password:
Authenticated to <IPADDRESS> (via proxy) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_FIG_SET_PARENT = "90039a7f-7428-4791-8a24-1e5aeac56fec"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8"
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to <IPADDRESS> closed.
Transferred: sent 3400, received 4040 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4975.8, received 5912.4
debug1: Exit status -1
```

(I have to precise that ssh connection is working perfectly when i initiate it from the jumphost)

Thanks by advance !

I'm trying to connect to a device using jumphost with this

| MY PC |  ->  | JUMPHOST |  ->  | myHost |

But once authenticated on myHost, i got an error "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0" and the session close

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to authenticate my SSH to github for my bootcamp. Not paying attention that I only needed to verify my key, I went down this rabbit hole thinking that "**PTY allocation request failed on channel 0**" was disrupting my connection to host.

as described in answer number 1 on this 16 year old [forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75731641/pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0-on-device-using-jumphost) The PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 is a "[red herring](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/red-herring#:%7E:text=A%20red%20herring%20is%20a,be%20done%20intentionally%20or%20unintentionally.)".

In other words your connection is established but make sure your fingerprint matches the hosts fingerprint. (or so I did)

my session log:

```
 $ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-ea6f11ef
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-ea6f11ef
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/herna/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/herna/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/herna/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:4k3SEpBhP2FlW9/xYZihgOMJZLMvD8T++kxPlmUnKfo
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:4k3SEpBhP2FlW9/xYZihgOMJZLMvD8T++kxPlmUnKfo
debug1: Server accepts key: /c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:4k3SEpBhP2FlW9/xYZihgOMJZLMvD8T++kxPlmUnKfo
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/herna/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.114.3]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /c/Users/herna/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /c/Users/herna/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /c/Users/herna/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: pledge: fork
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi Skidesco! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2420, received 2492 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 16698.9, received 17195.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Login as root and try theese:

`lsof /dev/pts`

if no users are reported as using "pts":

`ls /dev/pts`

if the folder is empty:

`umount /dev/pts`

`mount -t devpts /dev/pts /dev/pts`

Now the following command shoud return some allocated tty's:

`ls /dev/pts`

If it's true, let try to redo what you wanted in the object.